# How to play video which are situated at my own server first download then play or play simultaneously

Tags: android

I am able to play youtube  video through webview but not able to play video which are situated at my own server

Comment: that is as per your requirement you can use both ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually better to play the video directly from the server and give an option to download the view if the user prefers.

**Play the video**

```
 String SrcPath = "link.fileformat";


   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
   myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(SrcPath));
   myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   myVideoView.requestFocus();
   myVideoView.start();
   }
```

**Download Video to SdCard:**

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(provide any URL);
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/download/";
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "PATH: " + PATH);
            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();

            String fileName = "Test.mp3";


            File outputFile = new File(file, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

                fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);

            }
            fos.close();
            is.close();

            // }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + e);
            Toast.makeText(myApp, "error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
```

and do `add` the required `permissions`

Comment: Which approach are you gonna use ?